# products of categories or categories of product listing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, friendly-id

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
    extend FriendlyId
    translates :name, :slug, :description
    friendly_id :slug_candidates, use: :globalize
    globalize_accessors :locales => [:tr, :en, :ar], :attributes => [:name, :slug, :description]
    has_and_belongs_to_many :categories, join_table: 'products_categories'
```

---

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
    acts_as_nested_set
    extend FriendlyId
    translates :name, :slug, :description
    friendly_id :slug_candidates, use: [:globalize, :slugged, :finders]
    globalize_accessors :locales => [:tr, :en, :ar], :attributes => [:name, :slug, :description]

    has_and_belongs_to_many :products, join_table: 'products_categories'
```

---

```
Product.search_by_product_name(parameters[:oyun]).eager_load(:categories)
```

---

```
Product.eager_load(:categories).search_by_product_name(parameters[:oyun])
```

I want to list categories of products or categories of products.

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Stack Overflow! Can I suggest that you include a clear description of the problem that you're facing to this question?

Comment: I want to list categories of products or categories of products in view.

Comment: This question still is a bit unclear, but what you may be looking for is the `categories` function on a `product`.  since they are related by `has_and_belongs_to_many`, rails automagically puts a function on each of the objects that returns all the associated objects, with the function name of the first argument to `has_and_belongs_to_many`.

Comment: I want to get with "includes".   there is N + 1 query problem in this state